# Regex for greater than or less than 3 digits and characters

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

This is probably just the usual "Oh no look another person asking for regex" but I really cant figure this one out. What I need to do is find a simple regex that will match anything that's greater than or less than 3 digits. It must also match characters though.

Just a little explanation. I am trying to match anything that isn't the standard area code for a telephone number. so > 3 < including characters. I am using this for business rules and have already matched the positive version of the area code.

only one record is passed through the regex at one time so there are no need for delimiters.

Okay sorry about that here are some examples:

```
337   : does not match
123   : does not match
12    : does match
1     : does match
asd   : does match
as2   : does match
12as45: does match
1234  : does match
```

the opposite is really easy and can just be [0-9]{3} or [\d]{3}.

P.S. Its in java

Comment: Show us the "positive" version of what you want to match. Also some examples of good and bad strings. **For what language is this?** Wouldn't it be possible to just much with your "positive" regex and negate it using language features? Your little explanation is not enough to answer this.

Comment: In principle there's no reason why regular grammars cannot support a set difference (any grammar or regex represents a set of strings, so you'd subtract the set of 3-digit strings from the set of any-length digit strings) but I don't know if that's a common operator to provide for regular expressions - though maybe it's what Nitzan is suggesting?

Comment: @stema sorry about that the answer has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
^(?:(?!(?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\d))[a-zA-Z\d])+$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?358sd).

Explained

```
^                                # match the start of the string (not needed with the matches() method)
    (?:                          # start of a non capturing group
        (?!(?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\d))   # combined lookarounds, fails if there are 3 digits following with not a digit before and ahead of those 3 digits
        [a-zA-Z\d]               # match one ASCII letter or digit
    )+                           # repeat this at least once
$                                # match the end of the string (not needed with the matches() method)
```

Comment: Thanks for this :) Was really helpful. Finally managed to get my rules to work.

Answer (score 3):

Now this is the solution with "a-z" (because it seems to be so common):

```
^(?!\d{3})[a-z0-9]{3}$|^[a-z0-9]{1,2}$|^[a-z0-9]{4,}$
```

... and this is the true solution, which matches everything except three characters that are all digits:

```
^(?!\d{3}).{3}$|^.{1,2}$|^.{4,}$
```

http://regexr.com?358u9

Because we are just checking three alternatives, it's pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Hi, what I need is "one to two or four and more digits or characters" there fore it will match: a, as1, 121vc, 12, 1234 and so on..

Comment: Ok, but by what characters are this sequences of digits and characters delimited? I assume, by whitespace?

Comment: Take a look at my edited question. sorry for not explaining further. There is no delimiter. only one record will be passed at a time so there is no need to worry about that

Comment: Edited. But note that this contradicts the title, where it says "in a string". Within a string there have to be delimiters. Now it is checking the whole string from start to end.

Comment: Oh, now the samples show something else. I will look into this later.

Comment: hmm there is a problem with this it still seems to match 'sad' also sorry about that...

Comment: It matches "sad" and according to your examples it should match "asd". Is this more complicated than I think? ;)

Comment: Ok, now it matches your examples. I hope that's ok, although you already marked it as solution.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I wish I could choose two solutions :/ stema's is shorter and his was submitted before yours was edited. Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem. I really like stema's regex and learned something from it. Sadly, it's wrong, because it doesn't match the "123Foo45" in his example. We don't even need the "a-z" here (actually, we must not use it). I will update my solution accordingly. Anyway, it was a fun regex training. :)

Answer (score -1):

Use negative look behind with \d{3}: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? This is pretty much stema's answer, which was accepted.